# sbass unable to read gringo output

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo, gringo

I'm running a simple ASP program:

```
%Defining possible states of each of the rook space
occupied(t; f).

%Generate all possible grids
{rook(X, Y, D) : occupied(D)} = 1 :- X=2..x, Y=2..y.

%Bound the grid with empty space
rook(X, Y, f) :- X=0, Y=1..y.
rook(X, Y, f) :- X=x+1, Y=1..y.
rook(X, Y, f) :- X=1..x, Y=0.
rook(X, Y, f) :- X=1..x, Y=y+1.

%Surrounding space is considered free path
freePath(X, Y) :- X=0, Y=1..y.
freePath(X, Y) :- X=x+1, Y=1..y.
freePath(X, Y) :- X=1..x, Y=0.
freePath(X, Y) :- X=1..x, Y=y+1.

%Generate empty path from the outside space
freePath(X, Y) :- rook(X, Y, f), freePath(X+1, Y).
freePath(X, Y) :- rook(X, Y, f), freePath(X-1, Y).
freePath(X, Y) :- rook(X, Y, f), freePath(X, Y-1).
freePath(X, Y) :- rook(X, Y, f), freePath(X, Y+1).

%Remove any grid where a rook is not adjacent to a free path
:- rook(X, Y, t), not freePath(X, Y+1),
                  not freePath(X, Y-1),
                  not freePath(X-1, Y),
                  not freePath(X+1, Y).

%Maximize the number of rooks by minimizing empty space
#maximize{1, X, Y : rook(X, Y, t)}.
#show rook/3.
```

In order to try to cut down the search space by breaking symmetries, I've been trying to use the [sbass tool that's on Potassco's website](https://potassco.org/labs/sbass/)

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After running make in the sbass file and getting the executable and I just run:

```
gringo ./rooks-game.lp -c x=5 -c y=5 | ./sbass
```

And it's throwing an error:

```
./sbass: unable to read input
```

What am I missing? According to the article, sbass should just be able to take the output of gringo.

Comment: Could you check the output of the gringo command? In my case (gringo version 5.5.0), it terminates with an error (duplicate constant definition); There seem to be a typo in your command -c x=5 -c y=5

Comment: It seems that sbass does not parse the header of the generated file; if you ignore the first line of the gringo output (tail -n +2), then sbass processes the gringo output

Comment: @tphilipp Thanks! That worked!